# jquery .animate() question

Tags: jquery

lets say I have two buttons (prev) (next) and some three divs of content underneath. two are hidden 1 shows.

is there a way to make it so if you click next, the current div animates left until it's out side the div and then it disappears and make another div come from the right and stop at the same position the first div was.

and also, if you click prev, make that new visible div move right and make the previously hidden div show up from the left .. kinda stuck here :\

Comment: i think you should learn javascript not jquery

Comment: First unofficial warning.  Don't abuse people trying to help you.  Its a simple concept almost everybody understands.

Comment: @Baruch yeah, I see your point.  Let's make it official.  We'll skip the nastygram and just suspend if you can't play nice.  The mod queue is long enough without your help, thankyouverymuch.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is exactly what you're looking for - a handy plugin! http://css-tricks.com/moving-boxes/

Answer (score 0):

See http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

The second example here sounds like what you are describing:
http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/int2.html

You'll just need to modify the fx, so:

> $('#your-parent-div-name').cycle({ 
>      fx:     'scrollLeft',
>     next:   '#next2', 
>      prev:   '#prev2' 
>   });